# How to force AVPlayer to pause buffering when it is in paused state?

Tags: ios, stream, buffer, avplayer, pause

I'm using AVPlayer to play video. I use `AVPlayer pause` to pause the player. But observing with Charles shows that the stream segments are still being downloaded when the player is in paused state.

I found [AVPlayer buffering, pausing notification, and poster frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10648963/avplayer-buffering-pausing-notification-and-poster-frame) but they said it was

> AVPlayer will buffer the video in several cases, none cleary
>   documented

Is this normal behavior? How to make buffering pause when player pauses?

Comment: Checkout `canUseNetworkResourcesForLiveStreamingWhilePaused` in [iOS 9](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerItem_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVPlayerItem).

Comment: canUseNetworkResourcesForLiveStreamingWhilePaused should be ok according to documentation, but it doesn't work in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to manage **preferredForwardBufferDuration** of avplayer currentItem. If you want to stop buffering set value to 1 because if you set it to 0 it will be set up automatically

```
self.avPlayer.currentItem.preferredForwardBufferDuration = 1;
```

**From Apple documentation:** This property defines the preferred forward buffer duration in seconds. If set to 0, the player will choose an appropriate level of buffering for most use cases. Setting this property to a low value will increase the chance that playback will stall and re-buffer, while setting it to a high value will increase demand on system resources.