# How to set AVPlayer buffer empty in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, avplayeritem, avplayerviewcontroller

I am using AVPlayer for play Video in my app.

In my app, I have added functionality for play next/previous video so how can i set empty buffer.

so, if any one have solution for this help me.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10648963/avplayer-buffering-pausing-notification-and-poster-frame

Answer (score 2):

Try with

```
[self.player.currentItem cancelPendingSeeks];
[self.player.currentItem.asset cancelLoading];
```