# Is it possible to pause and resume buffering of AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, avplayer

Is it possible to pause and resume buffering of AVPlayer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Yes it is possible to some extent!*

You can use the playerItem's `preferredForwardBufferDuration` property to decide how much duration from the current playing time the player should prefetch. But sadly, this is only available from iOS version 10.

*Macro to check system version:*

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
```

You can now set how much duration you want to prefetch (in seconds).

```
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"10.0")) {
    NSTimeInterval interval = 1; // set to  0 for default duration.
    _player.currentItem.preferredForwardBufferDuration = interval;
    _player.automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = YES;

}
```

`automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling` is another property which enables the `autoplay` or `autowait` feature in avplayer. Because the player is likely to stall frequently if the `preferredForwardBufferDuration` is set to a smaller duration.

You can also use the playeritem's `canUseNetworkResourcesForLiveStreamingWhilePaused` property to set if the player should continue or pause buffering when the player is in pause state. This is available from iOS 9 onwards.

```
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"9.0")) {
_player.currentItem.canUseNetworkResourcesForLiveStreamingWhilePaused = NO;
}
```

> The condition check for the system version is very important. You can
>   use the macro mentioned above to do this. Otherwise the app will
>   crash.

***UPDATE - swift:***

```
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            player.currentItem?.preferredForwardBufferDuration = TimeInterval(1)
            player.automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = true;
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't work for remote media file using progressive downloading. Maybe this is just for live streaming?

Answer (score 1):

according to my test,`preferredForwardBufferDuration` should be greater or equal to 1.0,if it is below 1.0,default buffer duration will be used.

Answer (score 0):

AV player buffers the video in several cases, however no clear documentation on them. You can check currentItem.loadedTimeRanges to see what's going on more info can be found on this thread [AVPlayer buffering, pausing notification, and poster frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10648963/avplayer-buffering-pausing-notification-and-poster-frame)