# ios playing 3 videos one after another

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, avplayer

I am trying to start a new video with no delay as soon as the first video ends.  I tried using the AVQueuePlayer but there is some delay when the first video ends and the second starts.

I need this to be sample synchronous.  ie if video 1 is 10.25 seconds long then when I have been playing for 11.5 seconds video 2 should be 1.25 seconds in.

I have been experimenting with keeping 3 AVPlayer objects where I preRoll each player using the same master clock.  I am then trying to intercept the `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification` and then calling `setRate:time:atHostTime:` to start the next video going.  However I'm not getting any video playing.

I pre-roll my videos using the following code:

```
- (void) preRollPlayer: (AVPlayer*) pPlayer withMasterClock: (CMClockRef) masterClock atTime: (NSTimeInterval) time
{
    [pPlayer setRate: 0.0f];
    [pPlayer play];

    [pPlayer seekToTime: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds( time, 1000000 ) toleranceBefore: kCMTimeZero toleranceAfter: kCMTimeZero];
    [pPlayer setMasterClock: masterClock];

    __block volatile int32_t completed  = 0;
    [pPlayer prerollAtRate: 1.0f completionHandler: ^( BOOL finished )
        {
            OSAtomicIncrement32( &completed );
        }];

    while( completed == 0 )
    {
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval: 0.01];
    }
}
```

I then call preRoll as follows:

```
if ( pAudioVideoEntry.beforeVideoReader )
{
    [self preRollPlayer: pAudioVideoEntry.beforeVideoReader.player  withMasterClock: hostClock atTime: currentTime];
}

{
    [self preRollPlayer: pAudioVideoEntry.videoReader.player        withMasterClock: hostClock atTime: currentTime];
}
if ( pAudioVideoEntry.afterVideoReader )
{
    [self preRollPlayer: pAudioVideoEntry.afterVideoReader.player   withMasterClock: hostClock atTime: currentTime];
}
```

I finally start the video as follows:

```
[pAudioVideoEntry.beforeVideoReader.player  setRate: 1.0f time: kCMTimeZero atHostTime: syncTime];
    pAudioVideoEntry.playingPlayer  = pAudioVideoEntry.beforeVideoReader.player;

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                         selector: @selector( beforeVideoEnded: )
                                             name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                           object: pAudioVideoEntry.beforeVideoReader.playerItem];
```

What is odd is that I do not hear the audio, the notification is never sent and every call to my `AVPlayerItem`'s output `AVPlayerItemVideoOutput`'s `hasNewPixelBufferForItemTime` returns false.  So I'm guessing the video has not started.  Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in classic style around an hour after I post this (having spent most of the day battling over it) I find a simple solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11337690/131140

Using an `AVMutableComposition`I can add each video in sequence into the composition and I get perfect playback:

```
    // Fill in the assets that make up the composition
    CMTime time             = kCMTimeZero;
    for( AVAsset* pThisAsset in pAssets )
    {
        CMTimeRange timeRange   = CMTimeRangeMake( kCMTimeZero, pThisAsset.duration );
        [pComposition insertTimeRange: timeRange ofAsset: pThisAsset atTime: time error: nil];

        time        = CMTimeAdd( time, pThisAsset.duration );
    }
```

I'm having a slight bug with the video images playing back out of sync with the audio but the audio is performing perfectly.  Massively simplified my code as well!

Comment: Hi Goz will you please provide me an example with the above code.

Comment: @MaheshNarla: I've answered your question.  Hope it helps.