# Fast uploading video and play without buffering video from URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, ftp, avplayer, avcapturesession

In my Application I'm capturing 10 second of video and upload to server by FTP and Other user can watch this video by URL(s) from web service response.

As per my question I want to capture video with good quality with small size so It easy to upload video by FTP. Right now I'm using **.mp4** video formate to upload video if anybody know best video formation that can increase uploading speed then guide me.

Second I'm getting all those uploaded video in the response of  web service as a **URL(s)**.
In response there are many URLs so I need to play video in queue means one-by-one and end user can do swipe left to move on NEXT video and swipe RIGHT to previous video. [You can see my code here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4218090/pre-buffering-for-avqueueplayer/39036307#39036307)

Every thing is working good but problem is **take much time** to **upload** and **play** *(buffering time)* video.

Please guide me on this points.

> COMMENT : Get success in the compress video 20 MB to 1.6 MB so uploading speed bit increase and Right now working with `AVQueuePlayer` for play video in queue but some time stuck video to playing.

Comment: You can play with presets available like `AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480` and see if it suits you in terms of quality and size.

Comment: @iphonic - Thanks but not suite in my application as per requirement.

Comment: To your first point:  you might experiment with newer codecs such as H.264/265; the compression is much more processor-intensive, but for comparable video quality,H.264 often reduces the content size by 50% or more as compared to MPEG-4, and H.265 can often reduce the size relative to H.264 by another 30-40%.  Fewer bytes means less upload time :)

Answer (score 5):

Yes,
May you upload video using chunk data in base64 format.
This is faster then FTP video upload & also useful when your internet connection is lost same time when you upload video in sequence.

Answer (score 2):

You can upload your files via SFTP, it is speed than FTP I think. Also your videos may bad performance with plays on http protocol.

You should follow this lines, **I hope it will help you**;

- Upload video via SFTP or Amazon S3
- Install to your server a stream engine like Wowza or Red5
- Transcode video for mobile (Usually wowza makes auto)
- Stream your videos over rtsp for android, hls (http) for ios

That its!

Good luck